# Validation for textbox in tabpage

Tags: c#

**Here's my situation:** I have a `TabControl` with three `TabPage`'s (`tabPage1` & `tabPage2` & `tabPage3`).In every page i have a 8 - 10 `textbox`. How i make  for `textbox, combobox, datetimepicker` - validation  in Windows Form Application ?
[image]

**This my form application**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fields validation in winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573302/fields-validation-in-winforms)

Comment: I need a short code for all row in one validation. Not separate each row

Comment: What are the validations do you need? Is this just `required field validation` for all controls?

Comment: I need to be checked if each row is completed or not, if it is not completed can not allow backup, and textbox  that have minim 3 letters (this is a condition). Ecuse me for my gramatical error :)

Comment: and by **each row** you mean every `textbox`, `combobox` etc ?

Comment: yes for every combobox,textbox and datetimepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Control`'s [`Validating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event with [`ErrorProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx).

I've created an example application.

It has a tab control with 2 pages:

- TabPage1

  - textbox2
  - textbox3
  - textbox4
  - textbox5
  - combobox1
  - combobox2
  - combobox3
  - datetimepicker1
- TabPage2

  - textbox1

[image]

Add an `ErrorProvider` control from toolbox to the `form`.

In `form`'s constructor, subscribe to validating events for all controls:

```
textBox1.Validating += textBox_Validating;
textBox2.Validating += textBox_Validating;
textBox3.Validating += textBox_Validating;
textBox4.Validating += textBox_Validating;
textBox5.Validating += textBox_Validating;

comboBox1.Validating += comboBox_Validating;
comboBox2.Validating += comboBox_Validating;
comboBox3.Validating += comboBox_Validating;

dateTimePicker1.Validating += dateTimePicker1_Validating;
```

Here are the events checking for empty value:

```
bool IsValidated = true; //will be checked on button click
void dateTimePicker1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    DateTimePicker datetimepicker = sender as DateTimePicker;
    if (datetimepicker.Value == null)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(datetimepicker, "Required");
        IsValidated = false;
    }
}

void comboBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
    if(combo.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(combo, "Required");
        IsValidated = false;
    }
}

void textBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtbox = sender as TextBox;
    if (txtbox.Text == "" || txtbox.Text.Length > 2)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtbox, "Required");
        IsValidated = false;
    }
}
```

**`Validating` event fires when you lose focus from any control, but what if someone directly clicks on `Submit` button?**

To solve this problem, you can also validate all controls for all tabs on button click:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //traverse all Tab Pages
    foreach (TabPage tabpage in tabControl1.Controls.OfType<TabPage>())
    {
        foreach (TextBox txtbox in tabpage.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            textBox_Validating(txtbox, null);

        foreach (ComboBox combo in tabpage.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
            comboBox_Validating(combo, null);

        foreach (DateTimePicker date in tabpage.Controls.OfType<DateTimePicker>())
            dateTimePicker1_Validating(date, null);
    }

    if (IsValidated)
        MessageBox.Show("submitted");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("not submitted");
}
```

It'll show the error against every control(see following snapshot) and will not submit the form.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for  this code, but I did also. I want other  method that does not use provider error, but the error that displays text (no messagebox) and in code must check all the empty spaces and be at least 3 letters must be a single command for all. Not each row separately. For all ranks overall.

Comment: Well you can check for empty spaces in `textbox_validating` event handler. Where I'm checking for empty string, you can check for whatever condition you want to validate. As it comes to show a message to user, you can attach a `tooltip` with control to show the message.